# What is the definition of a prorelation?

Tags: gn.general-topology, higher-category-theory, uniform-spaces

In the context of quasi-uniform spaces, what is a prorelation?

In the [text I'm reading](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271523/1-s2.0-S0166864111X00159/1-s2.0-S0166864111002525/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHYaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIEyG3OL7jKqtRxUZecPpPMTy7MKXg6x0xOwNoPU3afPTAiEA7ROdtL2OIreRYuzEo5A7lwJbmVP3Y57Pu2gKyJ%2F1xIIqvQMIn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDOh8dG1VazP89ZAaniqRA%2BzIFRRLISMlOt5VoHRXR2c%2BB9c4Z0vrN34lw0CWoSyjjfO6BRTLHPymQwFfAqYZUuydlvHGdXd4Lnqrs%2BIqRiksU5Om6R1p%2FMZmZEjkAhFQ%2BPzTz5yeHQL1N8KH1rWNkYz0TqoNMPdp%2FM1CUbeS8YpTM7f4AdCwZycBf9D9XcyGlTaQuCybKJE9ageA6KlPaJ5Uaju%2B1eXa%2Fwp3jR8thkAJgbH9T3Rbgew036Kpkkdk2NXZ%2BnMdGSwsimiV8YpeCF66Rj7ji2AKxbSU1i%2FYDdBPgfPbHExibor9eNCyizBJbwvZemsnMOeDUWJM7xA1m2Latf5Aj9Osy79uNjOT3%2B57miRNCOkPxLrZANK51ozp%2FKZnt1sk5BtnIKB2C7Jf9FhDpiZAjbua6Yj2MQhmWFTMomY7wlZWsgpfT6ryAIJyAzbMNp%2FJ7fZreY0M8Ee4vKHiyKRZJ%2BnBrmxpjxibGdy4YBDebqJC41yDb%2BeA96Jx069%2FDrvgQEY7%2FZ00Yjyq6fZVmDV9nl6xcnUuTTi5YqdfMLq8lPUFOusBMBWAwIUj8O0KLi5OVrsHqWUhEH%2BV5xdaGzUYbV5viRtUyu%2FT8eW8i%2F9VFQZzvp0sxwX%2BiUBYkTLNQ75tgRcU%2BQJu%2BgcoZVNeYWk5jLz7%2FHfmJJlDD5%2FbLy4OI70G4BqbrR4QoJcofyKUahsPdMf2R0jq9f94iS80AvCKhx4tB0XAOrMenDuXaOwOah9wc8CIf5XTbkOCqrwAmdsSHrU%2F64Da9DVmXcF9YJKR2TSOB9GKyxmDTpqza4qDDylmc%2BCn22fQX0EGJmChimDq790NhaP6OAfbp0duZoEiEOaM5DGUOvpd7Drx96bARw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200426T064008Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYTP7H5NX7%2F20200426%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=75ca1a3e573bdbe04aaf048236f10ea9575628ab6942313ba1b0b10f7d18e4fe&hash=764a457672941a119ff6e41372993800a8ad05551b0bfecc1ff35058bf7db03e&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0166864111002525&tid=spdf-cc04ed0d-7c55-4755-b8c9-639a0fb16a22&sid=1628b62c6c88f9444d399e6993c16b50d4bdgxrqb&type=client), they're defined as a down-directed upper set on relations X->Y.

Now, I'm fine with a down-directed up-set, but don't know of and couldn't find any preorder on a collection of relations from X to Y, let alone a partial order in order to define an up-set

Comment: The set of relations has a natural order : the inclusion. It's the one that is used in the first paragraph of the introduction, when they say $1_X\leq a , a\cdot a \leq a$ for preorders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, a prorelation is just a filter on the set of relations X to Y -_-